# Deprecate the ubuntu-desktop tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This first came up when [SE introduced](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/777/please-disable-displaying-a-tag-at-the-start-of-page-titles) displaying the most common tag at the start page s for SEO reasons.

Commenting on the following two questions and their new titles

- [ubuntu desktop - What native games are available? - Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6586/what-native-games-are-available)
- [ubuntu desktop - How do I make my purchased music be synchronized on Rhythmbox and in ~./ubuntuone/Purchased from Ubuntu One?   - Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16983/how-do-i-make-my-purchased-music-be-synchronized-on-rhythmbox-and-in-ubuntuone)

I said:

> The ubuntu-desktop is the most used tagged on the site, but is no doubt something very unlikely to be entered by users into a search engine, and therefore adds nothing for SEO. (Note I'm not saying I think we should stop using this tag.)

Jeff Atwood's response included (the Bold is his, not mine):

> I would also argue that this encourages proper and correct tagging of questions. **If the tag is objectionable in the title, then it's probably a bad tag practice** -- as you pointed out!

I wanted to seek the community's views on this.

Comment: A related question from earlier days. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/250/how-to-tag-the-ubuntu-editions-and-derivatives

Answer (score 10):

My current view (I often change my mind...) is that we should deprecate the tag.

One thing Jeff said in the [Stack Exchange blog comments](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) was

> What you should be asking yourself is this: for each tag you use, could a question with *only* that tag be valid?

I would argue that questions tagged only with `ubuntu-desktop` are meaningless - we don't actually know what the question is about, therefore according to the logic of one of the SE founders we shouldn't be using it.

If I look down the Ask Ubuntu homepage then of the 48 questions show the tag is used 11 times. I would say at least 40 of those questions could quite happily wear the tag.

But having over 80% of our questions tagged `ubuntu-desktop` is to my mind unnecessary. Tag the exceptions not the rule.

Comment: I agree 100%, if the tag doesn't add anything, or worse [if it is a meta-tag](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) -- it should not be used.

Comment: if anything you should tag server questions [server] to differentiate them and *assume* most questions are about desktop. Beyond that, I don't know how different Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop are in practice.. and what's so very very specific about Ubuntu Server that means you can't ask about it on, say http://serverfault.com ?

Comment: Completely removing server questions (and even the tagging of such questions) seems beyond the scope of this particular discussion (though I note that 4% of the questions here are tagged server)

Comment: In my mind -server questions should be here if they're small "I run a samba machine at home" type things, and serverfault for pros that run machines for others (ie. sysadmins).

Comment: I agree too, it wasn't obvious to me until it was pointed out in the blog but it makes total sense. Moving from ubuntu-server to just "server" would be a nice too.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the feedback here and in chat, I have deleted the [ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-desktop) tag.

However this does leave 49 posts tagged [untagged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/untagged) which need to be retagged something more meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I banged through the list giving them as good tags as I could manage.

There was only [one thread I couldn't handle](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13492/horoscope-or-astrology-software-in-ubuntu). It's a merge of a merge (nasty). I suggest we delete it (if that's possible) or just retag it to `software-recommendation`.

Or make me a moderator and I'll do that one too ;)