# Is the ubuntu-desktop tag immortal ?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

As of 2011-01-18, Jeff Atwood deleted the [ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-desktop) [tag](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/789/deprecate-the-ubuntu-desktop-tag/875#875).

One day later there are already new [ubuntu-desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-desktop) [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-desktop).
Considering all askers are relatively new to askubuntu, I suppose they were not addicted to this particular tag.

- Was the tag still available in tag suggestions ? [It may be possible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13485/auto-remove-tags-left-without-an-associated-question).
- What should we do now ? Should moderators delete this tag in the said questions ? Should I flag those questions for inappropriate tagging because I can't do it myself now ?

Comment: Please flag these questions while we follow up with the StackOverflow team.

Comment: Done. And already no more ubuntu-desktop questions!

Comment: Perhaps this should have the `discussion` tag replaced with `bug` and add the `status-completed` tag.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[image: This tag has been BURNINATED]

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been straightened out.